# How to get a chromeDriver object when using webdrivermanager on maven?

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

When i am using below code i am getting error on driver object creator.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;

public class NewTest {

private WebDriver driver;

public static void Setup()
  {

ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();

}

@Test

public void f() 

{

   driver = new ChromeDriver(); //**error-> ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type.

}

}
```

I have followed steps from https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `ChromeDriver` class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

See a working example [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/ChromeTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the setup method with

> WebDriverManager

in place of

> ChromeDriverManager

**The right way is:**

```
public static void setup() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
}
```